# Typeahead limpa o input quando o valor é fornecido por javascript

Tags: javascript, html, typeahead

Estou usando o [Typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) versão `0.9.3` para fazer auto-complete dos meus inputs.
Está funcionando bem, pega as informações do banco e mostra tudo certo.

Porém, caso eu queira definir algum valor para o input através de **JavaScript**. Quando o usuário clica em cima do campo e depois fora o valor do campo fica nulo.

Se eu colocar o valor na propriedade *value* do *input*. Isso não ocorre. Meu problema é que eu preciso atribuir valor para o *input* através do **JavaScript**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#teste').typeahead({
        limit: 50,
        minLength: 1,
        remote : '../db/dbAutoComplete.php?&query=%QUERY'
    });

    $('#teste').val('Valor que some se clicar fora do campo');
    //Estou forçando o valor a título de exemplo

});
```

E Meu HTML tem somente o input.

```
input type='text' name='teste' id='teste' value='' required
```

Comment: Qual é o retorno quando você pega o valor `$('#teste').val()`?

Comment: Primeiro. Obrigado pela ajuda.
Fiz o seguinte:
`input type='text' name='teste' id='teste' value='' required onblur ="BuscaRetorno()"`

function BuscaRetorno(){
    alert($('#teste').val());
}

Nesse momento ele trás a informação do campo certo. Depois disso que o valor do campo some.